# how to spawn a installer in a loop

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute a installer in a loop and every time it has to start the installer. But once the loop is executed once, it throws the below error and the script stops. Is there a way to stop this?

```
my $exp = Expect->new;
my $path="/opt/sample/Installer.pl";
for(my $i=0;$i<$a;$i++){
   $exp->spawn($path) or die "Cannot spawn $path: $!\n";
    ..
    ..
    ..
 }
```

Error:

```
Cannot reuse an object with an already spawned command at Installer.pl line 52
```

Expect documentation says :

Also note that you cannot reuse an object with an already spawned command, even if that command has exited. Sorry, but you have to allocate a new object.

Is there a way to handle this.

Comment: You have not mentioned which module you are using, so how could anyone answer your question, except to guess? Also, you have an unquoted string in your code, which means your code does not compile. You should never, ever, ever do that: Always cut and paste code and make sure it works, and preferably can replicate your problem.

Comment: sorry about that. I am using Expect Module from perl and trying to trigger a install in a loop. I have quoted the string in my code. I forgot to do it here. Will udpate it.

Comment: Perhaps your problem would be solved if you moved `my $exp = Expect->new;` inside the loop.

Comment: ya after moving it to the loop it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a comment as an answer:

Perhaps your problem would be solved if you moved `my $exp = Expect->new;` inside the loop.

This will make your Expect object go out of scope for each loop iteration. Do be aware that I do not know if this is the proper way to dispose of Expect objects.